# Any shortcut to find common String in ArrayList of ArrayList?

Tags: android

i have a list which contains ArrayList of string.
`[["1","2" ],["1","3","4"],["3","1"]]`.
 Is there any shortcut to find the string which is common to all ArrayList in the list? Assuming that there is at least a single String which is common to all. e.g. "1" in above case.

Answer (score 0):

use `Set` type instead of `List`. You can intersect sets to see only common elements:

```
Set<String> s1;
Set<String> s2;
s1.retainAll(s2);
```

Now `s1` contains only common elements for `s1` and `s2`